# How to change the text to blob uri?

Tags: javascript, url, blob, uri

In my code, suppose I have a String stored in a variable.

```
var strs = `alert("Hi");
console.log("Hello");`
```

What I want to do is, how to convert the **String** stored in variable **strs** into a Blob and convert that to a URL. Next process is to use that URL as URL for script tag.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The [Blob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob) constructor accepts an Array of BlobParts. BlobParts can be either other Blobs, ArrayBuffers or TypedArrays, or DOMStrings.

Your `strs` variable is a DOMString, so you can simply pass it in an Array to the Blob constructor and you will have Blob object representing a text file encoded in UTF-8 with your DOMString as content:

```js
var strs = `alert("Hi");
console.log("Hello");`;

const blob = new Blob([strs]);
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
document.getElementById('my-script').src = url;
```

```html
<script id="my-script"></script>
```